# where is a good place to learn css?

Tags: css

Does anyone know a good place to learn css? When I say css I do not mean how rules are matched . The w3school tutorials do a good job showing how changing certain properties effect a single element, but it doesn't show you how to bring all these skills together to build something bigger. Thanks

Comment: Experience. Nothing beats it. Also try http://CSS-Tricks.com

Comment: As it stands, this is nonconstructive--but if you changed it to, say, something like "What is a reliable source to learn CSS?" it would be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is some genious technology called "learning by doing". I would really recommend you to do this ;-)
Think of something somebody could need and build a website. There are plenty of websites which provide you with material:

- http://www.cssbasics.com/
- http://blog.jm3.net/2007/03/16/the-only-ten-things-to-know-about-css/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

AND last but not least NEVER ever refer to w3school.com because of http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @EvilP second link is now at http://blog.jm3.net/2007/03/16/the-only-ten-things-to-know-about-css/ :)

Comment: @jm3 thanks, I've changed it, just took me 10 years :-D

Answer (score 2):

I'd first like to point out that w3schools, although a good place to start, should ultimately be abandoned once you feel the need to explore further.

A great resource for CSS is MDN's (Mozilla Developer Network) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS).

There is also a list of separate tutorials [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning).

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn CSS is [Google](http://www.google.com). Seriously, if you want to build something bigger, you bring little things together and make something bigger out of them. By trial and error as well as researching on Google for some certain features, you can learn CSS and build something bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Clarke has written my two favorite books on CSS and web design at large. I recommend his latest - Hard Boiled Web Design:

http://www.hardboiledwebdesign.com/

Comment: I don't think this book specifically helps on real life situations as it mostly presents a way to do some advanced cutting-edge CSS stuff that you will rarely use in large corporations with need to have pixel by pixel.. Plus it doesn't cover basics such as css specificity etc.

Answer (score 0):

I find that Mozilla Developer Network has the best documentation for most web technologies, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Anyways, [here's their CSS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 0):

Best idea is to get some template from web and try to remake it - trying to change sth bigger gives you better overview of whole thing. Than You can try to make sth yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think www.codepupil.com plans to offer CSS lessons in the future.